# How to improve a MySQL query that have an internal join

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm using MySQL DB and as a result of a 3rd party client, we have some query that takes a long time. The 'problem' is that there is an outer-select using some internal-join without filtering results with 'where', and the 'where' is only on the "outer" section, which causes a join of 2 very big tables instead of joining 2 much smaller subsets of the tables (I can't control it, this is they way it is done... I must define them the join and they just add where clauses to it using this structure). Note that if the 'where' clauses would have been within the internal-join the join would be much-much smaller and the whole query would have been faster.

I've considered implementing the internal-join using a view, but it results the same performance. All fields compared by the join are indexed.

I was told that it can be improved with some DB's configuration tweaking, but no one could say what exactly.

Here is a paraphrase of the query (takes lots of seconds to minute to execute):

```
SELECT a.*,
       SUM(b.p1) p1
FROM
  (SELECT a.*,
          b.p1
   FROM a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.some_value = b.some_value)
WHERE a.some_value = 'x'
```

Just to explain, if I could write the query myself I would have written it like this (takes ~200ms to execute):

```
SELECT a.*,
       SUM(b.p1) p1
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.some_value = b.some_value
WHERE a.some_value = 'x'
```

Any idea how can I improve that?

Comment: Did you look at the `explain` output to check that at least it uses indices?

Comment: Yes, I did. I believe it does, but maybe I'm mistaken
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL              100000  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2  DERIVED  a  ALL              650612   
2  DERIVED  b  ref  index_on_some_value  index_on_some_value  67  a.some_value  106

Answer (score 0):

Your personal rewrite would be ok, however, by adding the AND b.y to the where clause kills your LEFT join to an INNER JOIN.  The AND b.y should be part of the join's ON clause to retain left-join qualification.

For indexes, table A should have index on (x, b_id) and table B have a covering index on (id, y, p1)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - I'm aware that my rewrite does the job, and I do have all indices. But the original problematic query is what I receive (cannot control) - the question is how can my DB can be configured to optimize and better support it (regarding your comment about b.y - I've rechecked and in my real scenario it is within the join - I've edited my original post)